# Fix ion-header to top of page when keyboard appears in Ionic app

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have a chat application, when I click into the `textarea` to start typing a new message the keyboard pushes up all the content above. This means that the `ion-header` disappears. I would like this to remain visible at the top of the screen at all times.

Here is an example GIF: https://i.imgur.com/a/GcmagJi

The `ion-header` code is:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons ion-fixed end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="closeChat()">
        <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

The `ion-footer` code is:

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-9>
        <textarea rows="3" [(ngModel)]="data.message" (keyup.enter)="sendMessage()" placeholder="Type your message ..."></textarea>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-3>
          <button ion-button (click)="sendMessage()">Send</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-footer>
```

In my `app.module.ts` file I have used:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  LongPressModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      scrollPadding: false,
      scrollAssist: true,
      autoFocusAssist: false
    }
  ),
  IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  DragulaModule,
  HttpModule
]
```

In my `chat.ts` I have:

```
constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) {
    this.keyboard.disableScroll(false);             
}
```

Despite all of these things nothing seems to keep the header fixed in place.

I have added the full code for my `chat.html` and `chat.ts` to the GitHib Gists below:

https://gist.github.com/christopherib/4b9e70590fb322bdc33ffbbe42d50685
https://gist.github.com/christopherib/cb3d234564c0feb1e8bf5b96f8d023c3

Comment: CSS position: fixed doesn't help on ion-header? Or <ion-header ion-fixed>?

Comment: Hi, just tested, unfortunately it makes no difference when I run the app on my phone.

Comment: @Chris can you create snippet of your code using codepen/plunker/jsfiddle etc? That would be easy to debug your issue.

Comment: Hi @VicJordan - not sure how to do this and the issue only becomes evident when I run the app on my device. I've updated my question with two URLs showing my full code. Thank you :-)

Comment: Is this issue only on iOS, Android or on both? Since I remember there being a bug involving fixed elements and the keyboard for iOS in Cordova a while ago, it might be related.

Comment: Good question. Only tested on iOS

Comment: Check it please on android device emulator

Comment: Same problem for me also, Is there any solution @Chris

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `keyboard.disableScroll(true)` right after `platform.ready()`

Or try to run `keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using?

```
<ion-content fullscreen><ion-content>
```

I'm currently using Ionic 4 and the header still looking good when the keyboard opens

I have the following structure

```
<ion-header no-border>
    <ion-toolbar>        
        <ion-fab-button>
            <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>             
        <ion-title></ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen>        
    ......
</ion-content>

<ion-footer no-border>  
    ......
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I open the app in IOS browsers. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

When the keyboard appears, run a js function. When doing so, give the header a negative margin.

Ex:

`function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.marginBottom = "-15px";
}`

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_marginbottom.asp

There is probably  more efficient solution but if position:fixed doesn't work this is the best one I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ion-item-divider under the ion-header like

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-item-divider sticky>
    <!-- Content -->
  </ion-item-divider>
</ion-header>
```

sticky properties used to when header up the they fixed on top

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I open the app in IOS browsers. Thanks anyway